# When sending money using Adaptive Payments configure the e-mail address the recipient gets

Tags: paypal

When sending money in the name of an user using Adaptive Payments to a recipient, is there a way to configure which user's e-mail address from those they added to PayPal will the recipient see/get?

Comment: `senderEmail` seems to be it as listed here (also a `sender.accountId` option): https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/ 

Does this answer your question? :)

Comment: But is this used only to select the account of the sender, or is this also information which the recipient gets?

Comment: Pretty sure the user should see it as well - yet to see an API which masks sender especially when its a verified one. Unfortunately unable to test for you since PayPal has a lot of regulatory pain for me here in India. Any chance you could run a $1 test? Can document this as an answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

**There are clearly 2 questions here:**

1. Can I configure senderEmail while using Adaptive Payments?
2. Will recipient(s) see the senderEmail?

**Assumption:**

You are the caller of the API

**Answers:**

1. You *can configure* the senderEmail to any of the email addresses associated with your PayPal business account, but **only your primary email address will be seen** by recipient.
2. This depends on if the payment was a *simple payment / parallel payment or chained*. In simple or parallel, **all recipients** see the sender's (primary) email. However in a *chained payment* scenario where there is a primary receiver and 1+ more secondary receivers, only the **primary receiver** will see the sender’s (primary) email; but the secondary receivers **will not**.

To learn more about Adaptive Payments the URL shared by Angad is a good starting point. For learning more about the type of payments(simple, parallel or chained) you may also want to refer to the PDFs on: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/